# При изменении экрана список (навигация) не переходит на следующую строчку, а просто скрывается сама собой

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Вот ссылка на код помогите (:(

```css
* {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  min-width: 320px;
}

.button {
  margin-right: 117px;
}

.media>ion-icon {
  margin-right: 33px;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 117px;
}

.navmenu {
  height: 80px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.topnav>ul {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #5E81FE;
}

a {
  color: #697CA6;
  padding-left: 42px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Quicksand';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 15px;
}

.nav {
  display: block;
}

.header__content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1400px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 650px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Верстка</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT Sans:wght@400;700&family=Quicksand:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <header class="header">
    <!-- Весь контент шапки -->
    <div class="header__content">
      <!-- Навигация -->
      <div class="navmenu">
        <!-- Логотип -->
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Логотип">
        </div>
        <!-- Навигация -->
        <nav class="nav">
          <div class="topnav">
            <ul>


              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Documentation</a></li>

            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- Иконки медиа -->
        <div class="media">
          <ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon>
          <ion-icon name="call"></ion-icon>
          <ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon>
          <ion-icon name="logo-medium"></ion-icon>
        </div>
        <!-- Кнопка -->
        <button class="button">
                Get Started
            </button>
      </div>
      <!-- Конец навигации -->





    </div>
  </header>


  <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
  <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно свойство `flex-wrap: wrap` для `.topnav>ul`.

```css
* {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  min-width: 320px;
}

.button {
  margin-right: 117px;
}

.media>ion-icon {
  margin-right: 33px;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 117px;
}

.navmenu {
  height: 80px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.topnav>ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #5E81FE;
}

a {
  color: #697CA6;
  padding-left: 42px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Quicksand';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 15px;
}

.nav {
  display: block;
}

.header__content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1400px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 650px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Верстка</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT Sans:wght@400;700&family=Quicksand:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <header class="header">
    <!-- Весь контент шапки -->
    <div class="header__content">
      <!-- Навигация -->
      <div class="navmenu">
        <!-- Логотип -->
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Логотип">
        </div>
        <!-- Навигация -->
        <nav class="nav">
          <div class="topnav">
            <ul>


              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Documentation</a></li>

            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- Иконки медиа -->
        <div class="media">
          <ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon>
          <ion-icon name="call"></ion-icon>
          <ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon>
          <ion-icon name="logo-medium"></ion-icon>
        </div>
        <!-- Кнопка -->
        <button class="button">
                Get Started
            </button>
      </div>
      <!-- Конец навигации -->





    </div>
  </header>


  <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
  <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```